# How does the $grid-column-alias Sass variable work...?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Setting it to false is supposed to utilize only "column", but in my project it has no impact in the compiled CSS -- both column and columns are still there.

I'm interested in getting it to work because [the Foundation 6 grid documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#basics) indicates it will reduce file size by 3 to 5%. I have tried all of the following and none have produced the desired result:

```
// Selector used for an alias of column (with @extend). If false, no alias 
is created.
    $grid-column-alias: '';
    $grid-column-alias: 'false';
    $grid-column-alias: false;
    $grid-column-alias: 'column';
```

Has anyone else used this successfully? I'm declaring it with my other grid-column variables. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your build task ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code here https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/scss/grid/_classes.scss#L170 it appears that it is checking for

```
@if $column == 'column' and has-value($grid-column-alias)
```

`has-value` returns false for anything falsy, so this implies setting $grid-column-alias to false should work... testing it quickly in an empty ZURB template I see that when I update my `_settings.scss` to have `$grid-column-alias: false;` I no longer get `.columns` classes.

If this isn't working for you, perhaps you're setting it after you've already included the mixin? If you could explain a little more about your scss and build setup perhaps that would help track this down.

Comment: Glad to hear it works somewhere. I'm not using `_settings.scss`, but all other `$grid-column-` variables work fine in the location I'm calling them.